# How to check a conn write goroutine is blocked?

Tags: go, block, channel, goroutine

I'm writing a tcp bridge that pipes data from a conn to another conn, the process is duplex, that means the another conn may need to write data to the first conn.

I open four go-routines to handle the task, each one just does one of the things: read from upstream, write to downstream, read from downstream, and write to upstream. The read go-routine is simple:

```
func readUpstream(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 10)
        _, err := io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        pipeToDownstream(buf)
    }
}
```

In general, the function `pipeToDownload` just need a channel to write to it, and the `writeDownstream` function just read the channel, and then write it to the downstream conn, just like follow:

```
func pipeToDownstream(buf) {
    downPipe <- buf
}

func writeDownstream(conn *net.Conn) {
    for {
        data := <- downPipe
        _, err := conn.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But, in my case, the data from upstream is a video stream, I need to ensure the real-time pipe, that means if the downstream is writing, just the last frame read from the upstream should be reserved, and then the write downstream routine read from the reserved data and then write it. Because the video stream needs big bandwidth, but sometimes the client bandwidth is not enough to send data, and then the write downstream routine will be blocked, and then if use `pipeToDownstream` function directly will block the `readUpstream` go routine.

So, I added a flag to represent the `writeDownstream` is writing, the read data from `readUpstream` should be reserved if the flag is `1`, else should pipe to the channel directly. This means I need to add a mutex to ensure thread-safe for the `flag` and the `reserved` field.

How should I do?

Comment: First, you shouldn't use TCP for video streams if you don't mind some data being lost in transit. That's what UDP is for.  With UDP, just let the network layer take care of this--it should happen without your application ever caring.  Second, you should probably use `io.Copy` (https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) instead of implementing that yourself.

Comment: @Flimzy my problem is not how to implement this, but how to ignore delayed frames

Comment: On an unrelated `buf := make([]byte, 10)` shouldn't be inside of a for loop like that. You can initialize it above the for loops and save the number allocations you are doing.

Comment: I am bit confused by your question, but would be happy to help. So 'downstream' is from the server with a lot of bandwidth, and 'upstream' is to the server - where your upload bandwidth may be more limited, correct?   If I understand it correctly, you are trying to do what we normally call a non-blocking write. In this case, if you were just using the standard `write()` system call you would want this to be non-blocking. So if it blocks, you just don't write, and get the latest frame... If this is the case, you will probably need to use the `syscall` package and use a regular old `write()`

Comment: I can provide an example of that - but want to make sure this is what you want. You will need to set a `syscall.O_NONBLOCK` flag on your socket using `fcntl` which I don't think is exposed through the io libraries. So you will have to call something like this to do it `syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_FCNTL, ... )`

Comment: @EdH For example: the output bandwidth for downstream is 2mbps, the input bandwidth for upstream is 4mbps, and the video stream is 24fps, that means each frame of the video is about 4/24mbit. And then, the downstream could not be write in 4mpbs, some frames should be ignored from the upstream. In this case, if I receive one video frame from the upstream, I need to check the downstream is writing or not, if true, the frame should be ignored(just simplify the model, maybe should keep it for buffer), else it sould be written to the downstream. And the syscall could not resolve this problem.